# Android threads can't get notify() to work properly using wait() and notify()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait, notify

So I am writing an Android application which will do a count down when the user presses a button. A thread runs the count down. My problem is that when I pause the application I want the thread to stop counting and then resume once the application is back. My notify is not working correctly. Help thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mText;
    private EditText mUserInput;
    private CounterThread mCounterThread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    mUserInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
    mCounterThread = new CounterThread();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mCounterThread.running = false;
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mCounterThread.running = true;
    notify();//seems like this does nothing!
}

public void startCounterThread(){
    mCounterThread.start();
}

public void button_handler(View v){
    startCounterThread();
   }

public void updateSeconds(final long seconds){
    Runnable UIdoWork = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            String time = String.valueOf(seconds);
            mText.setText("Your file will open in " + time + " seconds");
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(UIdoWork);
}

private class CounterThread extends Thread{
    int count = 10;
    boolean running = true;

    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){
        while(count != 0){
            while(!running){
                try{
                    wait();//wait() will wait forever
                    //I don't want to put a time since 
                    //I have no clue when the user will resume again
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            updateSeconds(count--);
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: In onPause have you tried calling thread.wait()? Also just and FYI Android has the chronometer class that does this for you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modified code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mText;
    private EditText mUserInput;
    private CounterThread mCounterThread;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);
        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mUserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        mCounterThread = new CounterThread();
        mCounterThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCounterThread.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCounterThread.onResume();
    }

    public void startCounterThread() {
        mCounterThread.start();
    }

    public void button_handler(View v) {
        startCounterThread();
    }

    public void updateSeconds(final long seconds) {
        Runnable UIdoWork = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String time = String.valueOf(seconds);
                mText.setText("Your file will open in " + time + " seconds");
            }
        };
        runOnUiThread(UIdoWork);
    }

    private class CounterThread extends Thread {
        private int count = 10;
        private final Object lock = new Object();
        private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

        public void onResume() {
            if(!isRunning){
                isRunning = true;
                synchronized (lock){
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }

        }

        public void onPause() {
            isRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (count != 0) {

                synchronized (lock) {

                    if (!isRunning) try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //
                    }
                }


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //
                }
                updateSeconds(count--);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

1. your field `running` must be marked as `volatile`. It basically means that several threads could change it and all threads will see it.
2. do not expose monitor objects out of a `Thread` or a `Runnable`. It's quite bad idea to use activity as a monitor. It's quite bad idea to pass reference of activity anywhere.
3. you used different monitor objects: `Thread` and `Activity`. Use one inside thread.

Comment: Thank you. It worked and I understand wait and notify better know! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that is not working because wait() and notify() work over an object that is used as a lock. When you run wait() in your run() method, you are using an instance of CounterThread as a lock, but when you run notify() inside your onResume() method, you are using an instance of MainActivity. CounterThread will never get notified. Your alternative is (in your onResume() method):

```
...
synchronized(mCounterThread) {
    mCounterThread.notify();
}
...
```